# Leap year exercise. but "else" has to print how many years there is left to next leap year

Tags: c++, leap-year

So I have almost just started coding. And I wondered if any of you guys could help me with this simple code.
I need to state how many years there is left till next leap year and I am lost.

```
int main()
{

int year;

cout << "Enter a year: ";
cin >> year;

if (year % 4 == 0)
{
    if (year % 100 == 0)
    {
        if (year % 400 == 0)
            cout << year << " is a leap year.";
        else
            cout << "There is " << 4%-year << " years till next leap year";
    }
    else
        cout << year << " is a leap year.";
}
else
   cout << "There is " << ???year << " years till next leap year";

return 0;
```

}

Comment: BTW, the expression `4%-year` is equal to `4 % (-year)`, if syntactically correct.  I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you had an `bool IsLeapYear(int year)` function, then you could do `if (!IsLeapYear(year)) { int nextLeapYear = year; while(!IsLeapYear(nextLeapYear)) nextLeapYear++; cout << "There is " << (nextLeapYear - year) << " years till next leap year"; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code. Please use below code for the same and try to understand your mistakes:-

```
int main()
{

    int year;

    cout << "Enter a year: ";
    cin >> year;
    int isleap = year % 4;
    if (isleap == 0)
    {
        isleap = year % 100;
        if (isleap == 0)
        {
            isleap = year % 400;
            if (isleap == 0)
                cout << year << " is a leap year."<<endl;
            else
                cout << "There is " << (4-isleap) << " years till next leap year"<<endl;
        }
        else
            cout << year << " is a leap year."<<endl;
    }
    else
       cout << "There is " << (4-isleap) << " years till next leap year"<<endl;

    return 0;

}
```